# How can I select the column using the column name in a different dataframe?

Tags: r

I want to select the column(or make a subset) using the column name in a different dataframe.

e.g.

A dataframe: 3 columns

- each column name: ab, cd, de

B dataframe: 10 columns

- each column name: n_ab, n_cd_e, n_de, ab, fg, n_ef, tt, yy, zz, n_a2

I want to make the subset of the B dataframe.

1. subset C dataframe
   n_ab, n_cd_e, n_de, ab
2. subset D dataframe
   ab

**How can I make C and D dataframe?**

I expected that I could make the subset B using this code.
but, I couldn't. Because the contains() only can make the subset by letter.

**3) How can select the column(or make the subset) using the condition(like >= ,  %in% , == etc.)?**

ge<-select(ge.n, contains('ge'))

Thanks

Comment: welcome to `stackoverflow`, please edit your question to include your code and sample in proper format.

Comment: Please take a read of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to ask a good question. Currently it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To create `C` you can use `grepl` with an `OR` pattern derived from the elements on `A`'s names.

```
C = B[, grepl(paste0(names(A), collapse="|"), names(B)), drop=F]
```

To create `D` you can use  `%in%` directly.

```
D = B[, names(B) %in% names(A), drop=F]
```

Outputs (C and D, respectively):

```
        n_ab     n_cd_e       n_de         ab
1 -0.4456620  0.4007715  1.7869131  0.7013559
2  1.2240818  0.1106827  0.4978505 -0.4727914
3  0.3598138 -0.5558411 -1.9666172 -1.0678237


          ab
1  0.7013559
2 -0.4727914
3 -1.0678237
```

Inputs:

```
set.seed(123)
A = setNames(as.data.frame(
  replicate(3,rnorm(3))),  c("ab","cd","de")
)
B = setNames(as.data.frame(
  replicate(10,rnorm(3))),  c("n_ab", "n_cd_e", "n_de", "ab", "fg", "n_ef", "tt", "yy", "zz", "n_a2")
)
```